# React - How to Populate one DropDown based on previous DropDown without updating the second default field

Tags: reactjs, select, dropdown

Currently, I have a setup along these lines where the second drop-down is populated by a previous selection.

The problem is the second field updating after the first field, I want to give to the user to choose the options in the second field (should stay on default after the first field).

**For example:** If the user chose Mazda, nothing happens, the second field is still on "Choose your model" but Behind the Scenes it update and when the user clicks on the second field it will see the options based on the first field

Bonus: I'll appreciate also another clean code with this solution (Not sure if I did it well).

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

const lookup = {
    "def": [
        { id: '1', text: 'Choose your model' },
    ],
    "mazda": [
        { id: '1', text: '1' },
        { id: '2', text: '2' },
        { id: '3', text: '3' },
        { id: '4', text: '4' },
        { id: '5', text: '5' }
    ],
    "bmv": [
        { id: 'a', text: 'a' },
        { id: 'b', text: 'b' },
        { id: 'c', text: 'c' },
        { id: 'd', text: 'd' },
        { id: 'e', text: 'e' }
    ]
}

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            dataValue: 'def'
        }
    }

    onChange = ({ target: { value } }) => {
        this.setState({ dataValue: value });
    }

    render() {
        const { dataValue } = this.state;
        const options = lookup[dataValue];
        return (
            <div>
                <select onChange={this.onChange}>
                    <option value="def">Choose your car</option>
                    <option value="mazda">Mazda</option>
                    <option value="bmv">BMV</option>
                </select>
                <hr />
                <select>
                    {options.map(o => <option key={o.id} value={o.id}>{o.text}</option>)}
                </select>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cleaner approach would be a functional component for me with a memoized value. The second select is only enabled when the first one is not on default value. The default value for the second selects is spread in front of the possible options.

```js
import React, { useMemo, useState } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

const lookup = {
  def: [{ id: '0', text: 'Choose your model' }],
  mazda: [
    { id: '1', text: '1' },
    { id: '2', text: '2' },
    { id: '3', text: '3' },
    { id: '4', text: '4' },
    { id: '5', text: '5' },
  ],
  bmv: [
    { id: 'a', text: 'a' },
    { id: 'b', text: 'b' },
    { id: 'c', text: 'c' },
    { id: 'd', text: 'd' },
    { id: 'e', text: 'e' },
  ],
};

function App() {
  const [dataValue, setDataValue] = useState('def');
  const options = useMemo(() => lookup[dataValue], [dataValue]);

  const onChange = ({ target: { value } }) => {
    setDataValue(value);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <select onChange={onChange}>
        <option value='def'>Choose your car</option>
        <option value='mazda'>Mazda</option>
        <option value='bmv'>BMV</option>
      </select>
      <hr />

      <select disabled={dataValue === 'def'}>
        {[...lookup.def, ...options].map(({ id, text }) => (
          <option key={id} value={id}>
            {text}
          </option>
        ))}
      </select>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));

export default App;
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, yes it looks cleaner, thanks for showing me another way to code I shared.
But, still with the problem for which I opened the ticket.
Do you have a way to solve my problem?

I have some kind of solution but it's like cheating:

I changed the first array (def: []) to an empty array.
And I added another option to the second <select> so it will be my default option.

And it's kind of solved my problem. But again, feels that is not the best way :O

Comment: @OzBkl I ran this code in a sandbox and the behaviour was just as expected. What is not working for you function-wise with this solution?

Comment: @OzBkl Does this not work as expected? https://codesandbox.io/embed/focused-perlman-ecqs5?fontsize=14

Comment: @OzBkl I have updated the above code, does this reflect what you wanted? Now it always shows the default value first, change in `{[...lookup.def, ...options].map(({ id, text }) => (`

Comment: @OzBkl Now also hiding the second drop down, if the first is on default selection

Comment: thanks! 
Yes, now it works but I don't want to hide it, maybe disable is the solution, is there any way to make it disable if the user has not yet selected the first one?

Comment: @OzBkl I have updated my answer with a disabled property on the select. Does this solve your question?

Comment: Yep, Thanks! :)

Marked!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to implement in functional component then check below:

```js
// import logo from './logo.svg';
// import './App.css';
import { useState } from 'react';

function App() {

  var [companies, setCompanies] = useState([
    { name: 'company1',  jobs: ['job1-1', 'job1-2', 'job1-3']},
    { name: 'company2', jobs: ['job2-1', 'job2-2', 'job2-3']},
    { name: 'company3', jobs: ['job3-1', 'job3-2', 'job3-3']}
  ])

  var [selectedCompany, setSC] = useState('company1');

  function handleChange (e) {
    console.log(selectedCompany, e.target.value)
    setSC(e.target.value)
  }

  function render () {
    let company = companies.filter(company => {
              return company.name === selectedCompany
            })
    return (
      <div>
        jobs
        <select>
          {
            company[0].jobs.map((job, i) => {
              return <option>{job}</option>
            })
          }
        </select>
        
        companies
        <select value={selectedCompany} onChange={handleChange}>
          {
            companies.map((company, i) => {
              return <option>{company.name}</option>
            })
          }
        </select>
        </div>
    )
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {render()}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```